# Can you download app to your ad card and still play then

Tags: sd-card, storage, android-versions

I want to down load app to my ad card so I can download mode apps but it won't let me download apps to it and still play them

Comment: Apps have to be installed so the dex file can be created, you can't just "play" it from anywhere... Install normally and use App2SD/Link2SD (requires root) to move it to the SD card

Comment: How do you do that

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD). Its an app in the Playstore. But you need a *rooted* device.
Also if you want to move `.obb` files to your SDcard, you need to pay for it.
There is also a "How to" in the description of the app in the Playstore.